# How to set Preferences?

Tags: java, android

Is there any Wrong in this code to set Preference.. Because I am getting error "Unfortunately (App name) has stopped. Please help me. Is there any alternative method instead of addPreferenceFromResource(R.xml.preference);

```
package example.katta;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class Preference extends PreferenceActivity{

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
}

public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);
    }
}


}
```

Here is My xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<EditTextPreference
    android:key="Name"
    android:summary="Enter Your Name"
    android:title="EditText" />

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="checkbox"
    android:summary="Check This Box"
    android:title="Checkbox" />

<ListPreference
    android:entries="@array/list"
    android:entryValues="@+array/listvalue"
    android:key="list"
    android:summary="This is The List to choose From"
    android:title="List" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here is My array String.

```
<string-array name="list">
    <item>Option 1</item>
    <item>Option 2</item>
    <item>Option 3</item>
    <item>Option 4</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="value">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
</string-array>

</resources>
```

Comment: Its Empty.@SimonMarquis

Comment: I don't believe you!

Comment: Sorry @SimonMarquis
but i m new programmer. What to do?

Comment: open the logcat from Adroid Studio and remove any filters. Or exectue this command: `adb logcat`

Comment: i m using Eclipse. Removed filters...

Comment: So, watch the logcat panel and execute your app. Make sure your device is plugged in and assigned in the logcat viewer

Comment: Still getting error.

Comment: Of course you are, what you need to do is to copy-paste the error trace!

Comment: I m not getting any error in Eclipse. sorry but i m confused and not getting what u want to tell me. my error log is empty and logcat is too long and unable to post here.

Comment: I'm not interested in the error log, but in the logcat trace. Clean it before running your app, then run the app, and paste its content

Comment: its too long. Not able to post here..

Comment: Use pastebin.com for instance

Comment: 08-09 17:22:21.188: E/Trace(1118): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-09 17:22:22.998: E/WVMExtractor(38): Failed to open libwvm.so
08-09 17:23:15.598: E/ThrottleService(278): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: This is not the correct error, paste the complete logcat please

Comment: i can't.... what to do in pastbin.com??

Comment: www.pastebin.com allows you to paste a large file, and there, give us the permanent url

Comment: paste and then submited.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8nwdAVt7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is not valid:

```
android:entryValues="@+array/listvalue"
```

You should replace it with:

```
android:entryValues="@array/listvalue"
```

**EDIT:**
the array resource has another name:

```
android:entryValues="@array/value"
```

Comment: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'entryValues' with value '@array/listvalue').

Comment: Where is your array-strings defined ?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="list">
        <item>Option 1</item>
        <item>Option 2</item>
        <item>Option 3</item>
        <item>Option 4</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="value">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>

Comment: So use `android:entryValues="@array/value"` instead

Comment: yeah done..!! Thank You So Much... you are genius.. thanks a lot. @SimonMarquies

Comment: You're welcome, validate the answer if it's ok now ;)